# Position of camera on running Locomotive

Tags: three.js

I used three's SplineCurve3 to drive the locomotive dynamically, but I wanted to put a camera in the cab. At the same time, the position of the camera changes with the locomotive to achieve the actual effect of the locomotive. How to control the position of the camera on the curved path?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding the camera as a child to the locomotive Object3D? (eg. `locomotive.add(camera);`). The camera should then be transformed with its parent that is moving along the spline path.

Comment: I tried it, and the camera didn't work.

Comment: @ jayfield1979 I want your help.

Comment: Please share more details :)

Comment: @nylki I tried your approach again, but if I want to change the camera's angle of view differently from the original state, clicking the button won't go back to the previous view. Why?

Comment: @nylki Thank you very much . It ' s settled now .

Comment: @G.ao Glad you figured it out yourself. Next time make sure you provide some more info, especially some code sample. That way people can help you better!

Comment: @nylki That's fine. Thank you!